# Can a method in C# override another method and be virtual at the same time?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, virtual

Sorry if this is a stupid question or if it has already been asked; I've tried googling around and I'm not really in a position to be able to test this right now... So here goes:

Picture this scenario:

```
public class Bottom
{
    virtual public void foo()
    {
        doTheThing();
    }
}

public class Middle : Bottom
{
    virtual override public void foo() //this function will both override the parent's foo() and letting its child's foo() be over ridden
    {
        base.foo();
        doTheOtherThing();
    }
}

public class Top : Middle
{
    override public void foo() 
    {
        base.foo();
        doTheFinalThing();
    }
}
```

The middle one with the comment is the one I'm asking about.

Is this an ok thing to do? Is it conventional? Are the keywords even in the right order? Does it matter? What is the most correct way to do this?

Comment: Virtual method is virtual all the way down, you don't need to do anything for that. So just remove "virtual" keyword from the Middle version.

Comment: Before you ask, please try to compile code you're interested in. Your code will currently give a compile-time error, so it's clearly not "an ok thing to do".

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx): "You cannot use the new, static, or virtual modifiers to modify an override method.... the overridden property must be virtual, abstract, or override."

Comment: Pretty sure I understand now. Thanks guys  --

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The virtual method defined in the bottom base class means the method is virtual and calls to it will execute the most derived implementation. This behavior is inherited by all overrides.

This means you only need to specify the "override" keyword. The base method already makes sure it is virtual, so you don't need to specify that again in your overrides. The compiler won't even allow you to do that.

Also, many people will argue that you should "favor composition over inheritance", but that is another discussion. Doing multiple overrides like you do is ok and correct.